# Objective-C – Use library from another library

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sstoolkit

I'm using `SSToolKit` in my project. The SSToolKit project uses `GHUnitTest`. I want to use GHUnitTest in my project. Do I need to download and install GHUnitTest or can I use the one included with SSToolKit. What is the best practice to do in this situation? (my app is an iOS-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the one bundled with SSToolKit, there is no point in downloading another library. Basically, this is the same as if you downloaded the library alone - it is just bundled with another library.

If you try to add another GHUnitTest, it will create errors (not good :D ).